# How to add an application/script to ubuntu 21.04 launch bar?

Tags: launcher, 21.04

Let's add some fresh knowledge to the forum now Ubuntu 21.04 is out =). My question today is simple; what is the most elegant way to create launch bar shortcuts (e.g. to folders, applications or documents) in Ubuntu 21.04?

I tried to create a `.desktop` file which looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/azhirkov/apps/idea-IC-211.6693.111/idea.sh
Name=Idea CE
Comment=Idea CE
Icon=/home/azhirkov/apps/idea-IC-211.6693.111/idea.svg
```

in `/usr/share/applications` but it made no effect.

I even tried solutions like `gio set idea.desktop metadata::trusted yes` but again it made no effect, I still can't find an Idea launcher in desktop search nor it appears on launchbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Comment: @pLumo it is executable -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 199 Apr 28 11:25 idea.desktop

Comment: I generally use `alacarte` tool which always worked fine. But this questions has dozens of answers,  you should try some of them... 21.04 should be no different here.

Comment: The link you provided does not answer my question, because the selected question provides the solution for ubuntu versions prior to `19.10`, while I clearly stated that this question is for `21.04` where `gnome-desktop-item-edit` is not present

Answer (score 3):

In order to include your custom launcher on the Ubuntu 21.04 launch bar, put your `.desktop` file in the folder `~/.local/share/applications` in your home folder. Then, it will quickly appear in the Application Overview. Drag the icon from the Application Overview to the Ubuntu 21.04 launch bar, a.k.a. the Dock, and you are all set!

Make sure your `.desktop` file is valid. If it does not point to a valid executable file, the icon will not be included in the application overview.

Comment: This is not working for me :( Stuff is not getting picked up in `.local/share/applications`?

Comment: `.desktop` file must be valid (and also not contain instructions *not* to include). Eventually log out then back in.

Comment: `chmod +x` on the *.desktop file, and setting absolute paths in Exec / TryExec solved it for me!

Comment: Had to right-click and chose "Allow Launching" first

Comment: Not needed for it to work in the Application overview

Answer (score 1):

A very convenient solution is to use `alacarte`:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

That's a graphical user interface to configure various menues, one of which is the launch bar. (Or at least the respective programs can be found in the search, when hitting on these 9 squares at the bottom of the launch bar -- when you find them there you can right-click and sat "add to favorites".)

Comment: Very simple solution, which also works.

Answer (score 0):

I manually started `/home/<user>/seamonkey/seamonkey %u` and it came up ok.

When I right-clicked on the icon in the launcher, it did not have a menu entry saying "add to favorites" so it would be available on the launcher the next time I needed to start it up.

Then I copied the above `.desktop` file and edited it, and saved to `.local/share/applications` folder (name of `seamonkey.desktop`. (see below)
Then when I manually started seamonkey up again, then right-click the launcher seamonkey icon, the option to save to favorites was there.

This `.desktop` worked for me:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/home/<user>/SeaMonkey2/seamonkey %u
Name=SeaMonkey2
Comment=SeaMonkey2
Icon=/home/<user>/SeaMonkey2/chrome/icons/default/default.png
```

Problem solved.